# How to solve this phasor question without some sort of approximation?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, approximation

**Question:** Write $2\cos(100t + \frac{1}{3}) - \sin(100t-1)$ in the form $A\cos(\omega t + \phi)$. Find A, $\omega$, $\phi$ . (Hint: Phasor approach
may simplify your task.) (Remark: Leave your answers exact as real numbers maybe in the form of
mathematical expressions, and do not attempt to approximate them using decimal representations.)

**My attempt:**

$$-\sin(100t-1)=\cos\left(100t - 1 + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Rewrite using this identity:

$$\underbrace{2\cos\left(100t + \frac{1}{3}\right)}_{=z_1} + \underbrace{\cos\left(100t - 1 + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)}_{=z_2} $$

$z_1$ in phasor is $z_1 = 2 \angle{\frac{1}{3}rad}$ which is $z_1 = 2 \angle{19.0986^{\circ}}$

$z_2$ in phasor is $z_2 = 1 \angle{-1 + \frac{\pi}{2}rad}$ which is $z_2 = 1 \angle{32.7042^{\circ}}$

This is where I am struggling because in order to proceed I have to take the approximations otherwise how can I convert it to rectangular form in order to perform addition over these two complex numbers?

Comment: Well, the answers will just involve trig functions evaluated at some weird angles that don't allow for simplification.

Comment: **Hint:** Convert directly to rectangular then back to polar and then rectangular again and then you will have you final answer.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... "this" in your title means nothing to anyone.

Comment: @Caporal Could you elaborate on the hint a little?

Comment: The answers to [trigonometry of interfering waves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210580/trigonometry-of-interfering-waves) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that
$$A\cos(\omega t+\phi)=\big(A\cos(\phi)\big)\cos(\omega t)-\big(A\sin(\phi)\big)\sin(\omega t)$$
And
$$2\cos(100t+1/3)-\sin(100t-1)\\=2\left(\cos(100t)\cos(1/3)-\sin(100t)\sin(1/3)\right)-\big(\sin(100t)\cos(1)-\cos(100t)\sin(1)\big) \\ =\big(2\cos(1/3)+\sin(1)\big)\cos(100t)-\big(2\sin(1/3)+\cos(1)\big)\sin(100t)$$
So to write $2\cos(100t+1/3)-\sin(100t-1)$ as $A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$ we clearly need $\omega=100$ and we need to find $A,\phi$ such that

$$A\begin{bmatrix}\cos\phi \\ \sin \phi\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\cos(1/3)+\sin(1) \\ 2\sin(1/3)+\cos(1)\end{bmatrix}$$

You can see that
$$\frac{\sin \phi}{\cos \phi}=\tan\phi=\frac{2\sin(1/3)+\cos(1)}{2\cos(1/3)+\sin (1)}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Is it like this: $$A^2 = 2^2 + 1^2 + 2 (2) (1) \cos( 1/3 - 1 )$$

$$A^2 = 4 + 1 + 4\cos( 1/3 - 1 )$$

$$A^2 = 5 +4\cos( 1/3 - 1 )$$

$$A= \sqrt{5+4\cos \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$

Comment: And for \phi: $$\tan\phi=\frac{2\sin(1/3)+\cos(1)}{2\cos(1/3)+\sin (1)}$$
$$\phi= \arctan\left(\frac{2\sin \left(1/3\right)+\cos \left(1\right)}{2\cos \left(1/3\right)+\sin \left(1\right)}\right)$$  Since I don't want to put in decimal form?

Comment: $A$ will be just the magnitude of the vector on the right hand side. Otherwise correct.